# convert a column(string) in csv file to a tuple of ints

Tags: python, csv

Currently, I process a file using the `csv` module, which creates a list of dictionaries.

```py
import csv
file = open('csvfile.csv')
lines = csv.reader(file)
header = next(lines)  # ['name', 'price', 'date']
# when I do the following
for line in lines:
    print(line)
# I get the following     
['xxxx', '5.00', '2/23/2023']

# assigning types to the columns to do type conversion using a function
types = [
    str,
    float,
    str  # this need to be a tuple
    # tried tuple(map(int, cannotchoosecolumn.split('/')))
    # did not work
]

# now to create a list of dicts
alist_of_dicts = [
    {
        name: func(val)
        for name, func, val in zip(header, types, line)
    }
    for line in lines
]
```

How would I select the third column `str(2/23/2023)` to change to a `tuple(2, 21, 2007)` using the format I am currently using?

Comment: Please fix the syntax of the code you posted, the current code wouldn't run. The code you shared is just a really roundabout way of reading a single line of data and casting the various columns into appropriate types. Your question appears to be "How can I convert the string `'2/23/2023'` into a tuple?" - which is simply splitting it over the `'/'` character, which is an extremely trivial operation ([`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)) (note that you also made a typo, since you probably don't want `'2/23/2023'` as `tuple(2, 21, 2007)` - be precise.)

Comment: The csv module as you are using it does not create a list of dictionaries.  It creates a series of lists.  It CAN produce a series of dictionaries, but not like that.

Comment: @ Grismar yes I am trying to convert that string to a tuple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a function to your `types` list:

```py
import datetime


def read_date(s):
    d = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%m/%d/%Y")
    return (d.month, d.day, d.year)


header = ["name", "price", "date"]
lines = [["xxxx", "5.00", "2/23/2023"]]
types = [
    str,
    float,
    read_date,
]

alist_of_dicts = [
    {name: func(val) for name, func, val in zip(header, types, line)} for line in lines
]

print(alist_of_dicts)
# prints: [{'name': 'xxxx', 'price': 5.0, 'date': (2, 23, 2023)}]
```

This is hard to understand code though. Instead, I recommend you use `csv.DictReader` to read the csv as a dictionary of strings -> strings, then transforming the columns

Comment: this works I had tried something similar but I could not figure out how to call the function w/o input an argument that corresponded with the column

Answer (score 2):

Use a `csv.DictReader` and convert the columns as you read them:

```py
import csv

with open('csvfile.csv', newline='') as file:
    a_list_of_dicts = []
    for line in csv.DictReader(file):
        line['price'] = float(line['price'])
        line['date'] = tuple(int(n) for n in line['date'].split('/'))
        a_list_of_dicts.append(line)

print(a_list_of_dicts)
```

csvfile.csv

```
name,price,date
xxxx,5.00,2/23/2023
yyyy,6.75,2/24/2023
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'xxxx', 'price': 5.0, 'date': (2, 23, 2023)}, {'name': 'yyyy', 'price': 6.75, 'date': (2, 24, 2023)}]
```

Comment: but how would I use this in my list of types which use a function?

Comment: @capnhud This is just an alternate method.  Calling `str` on the column that is already `str` is a waste of time and the dict-per-line is already created on each line read.

Comment: I know during the csv parsing it is a ```string``` within a ```list``` of other ```strings``` but wanted to convert that ```string``` to a ```tuple of ints``` using a ```list of funcs```